# toString("X2") method from C# to Laravel

Tags: c#, php, laravel, laravel-7

I converted this method from C# to Laravel:

C# code:

```
using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
{
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in hash)
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and in laravel:

```
$text = hash('sha1', $txt);
$byte_array = unpack('C*', $text);
foreach ($byte_array as $b)
    $r .= chr($b);
```

but the result in laravel is not correct!

The value of sb (in c#) and $r (in laravel) is not equal.

How I can convert this method?

Comment: You should probably state what goes wrong. "Not correct" is very broad.

Comment: And to add to what Pallet wrote, how do you know it's the PHP code that is "not correct"?

Comment: Read this and rewrite your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I just run it. There are only two problems in your PHP code.
1. `$r` wasn't defined.
2. `$r` is lowercase but in C#, it was `uppercase`

therefore the final code is something like before

```
$r = "";
$text = hash('sha1', $txt);
$byte_array = unpack('C*', strtoupper($text));
foreach ($byte_array as $b)
    $r .= chr($b);
```

Comment: If you see a question where not all parts are presented or when the problem is described as "not correct". Don't answer it. In the long run it's better to not answer and let the asker edit the question until it's of good enough quality

Answer (score 0):

Much to complex ! If you the passwort in PHP entered as UTF8
this line should be enough:

```
return hash('sha256', $cleanPass);
```

If another encoding is used you might encode first to UTF8.